# Unable to ctrl+B or ctrl+click after updating Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I've updated Android Studio to 3.3.1 and I am unable to navigate to a layout file using ctrl+click or ctrl+B. It just opens the R.java file under build folder.